# Error while counting Column (Count1) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

ORA-00904: "COUNT1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

Error at Line: 8 Column: 73

```
SELECT a1.branch_name        AS myfavourite,
       COUNT(a1.branch_name) AS count1,
       SUM(count1)           AS total_purchase ,
       a1.branch_id          AS branch_id,
       c1.city,
       c1.Branch_description AS description,
       c1.userid             AS shopmailid,
       c1.image
FROM tbl_orderdetails a1
INNER JOIN tbl_ordermaster b1
     ON   a1.order_master_id=b1.ordermasterid
INNER JOIN tbl_user c1
     ON   c1.id      =a1.branch_id
WHERE b1.user_id='12'
GROUP BY a1.branch_name,
     a1.branch_id,
     c1.city,
     c1.Branch_description,
     c1.userid,
     c1.image
ORDER BY COUNT(a1.branch_name) DESC
```

I want to sum count1 and get value in total purchase.I got error like the above

Comment: Do you need both `count1` and `total_purchase` in the final result set, or is `count1` just there to perform the sum? With this grouping, aren't they always going to be the same value anyway?

Comment: ya both but in count1 i will get values like  10,12,1 and in total_purchase as 23

Comment: But both aggregates have the same `group by`. Do want every row to have the same total, or should they be grouped at a broader level than the count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm) is fairly clear that you can't use a column alias as you are trying to, within the same select list as you can *only* use it in the `order by`:

> **`c_alias`**  Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The `AS` keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the `order_by_clause` but not other clauses in the query.

You can work around that with an in-line view (as Vignesh Kumar showed) or a common table expression (CTE, also called subquery factoring, as vinoth_S showed). But both those answers only show you the `total_purchase` value, not the individual `count1` values for each row in the result set.

You can't just remove the alias and do `SUM(COUNT(a1.branch_name)) AS ...` since that would give you an ORA-00937 error - the grouping for the sum isn't clear.

You can use the analytic version of `SUM` to calculate both in one go though:

```
SELECT a1.branch_name        AS myfavourite,
       COUNT(a1.branch_name) AS count1,
       SUM(COUNT(a1.branch_name)) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS total_purchase ,
...
```

If the original query got:

```
MYFAVOURITE     COUNT1  BRANCH_ID CITY       DESCRIPTION SHOPMAILID IMAGE    
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
BR2                 12         12 Paris      Branch 2            12 image 2    
BR1                 10         11 London     Branch 1            12 image 1    
BR3                  1         13 New York   Branch 4            12 image 3
```

... then adding that analytic sum would give:

```
MYFAVOURITE     COUNT1 TOTAL_PURCHASE  BRANCH_ID CITY       DESCRIPTION SHOPMAILID IMAGE    
----------- ---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
BR2                 12             23         12 Paris      Branch 2            12 image 2    
BR1                 10             23         11 London     Branch 1            12 image 1    
BR3                  1             23         13 New York   Branch 4            12 image 3
```

... with the same overall total count value in all rows in the result set, which you said in comments is what you want.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08b20/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
With Cte(myfavourite,count1,branch_id,city,description,shopmailid,image)
As
(
SELECT a1.branch_name        AS myfavourite,
       COUNT(a1.branch_name) AS count1,
       --SUM(count1)           AS total_purchase ,
       a1.branch_id          AS branch_id,
       c1.city,
       c1.Branch_description AS description,
       c1.userid             AS shopmailid,
       c1.image
FROM tbl_orderdetails a1
INNER JOIN tbl_ordermaster b1   ON   a1.order_master_id=b1.ordermasterid
INNER JOIN tbl_user c1          ON   c1.id      =a1.branch_id
WHERE b1.user_id='12'
GROUP BY a1.branch_name,a1.branch_id,c1.city,c1.Branch_description,
     c1.userid,c1.image
ORDER BY COUNT(a1.branch_name) DESC
)
select sum(Count1) as total_purchase, myfavourite,branch_id,city,description,shopmailid,image from  Cte
group by  myfavourite,branch_id,city,description,shopmailid,image
```

Comment: How about adding an explanation of your solution?

Comment: what is cte ?@FrankSchmitt

Comment: CTE means Common Table Expression is the concept in (Sql Server & Oracle)

Comment: Try to Add Error Name

Comment: You're missing 'city' in the CTE column list, so you get ORA-32038. But the grouping means you just get the same value for `total_purchase` as the original `count1` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use any aggregate function for alias columns. The error is because of

```
   COUNT(a1.branch_name) AS count1,
   SUM(count1) AS total_purchase
```

this line..

Try this

```
Select myfavourite,Sum(count1),branch_id,city,description,shopmailid,image 
From (
      Select a1.branch_name As myfavourite,count(a1.branch_name) As count1,
             a1.branch_id As branch_id, c1.city, c1.Branch_description As description,
             c1.userid As shopmailid,c1.image 
      From tbl_orderdetails a1 
           Inner Join tbl_ordermaster b1 ON a1.order_master_id=b1.ordermasterid 
           Inner Join tbl_user c1 ON c1.id=a1.branch_id  
      Where b1.user_id='12' 
      Group By a1.branch_name,a1.branch_id,c1.city, c1.Branch_description, c1.userid, c1.image
     ) Tmp
Group By myfavourite,branch_id,city,description,shopmailid,image 
Order By myfavourite
```

Comment: @NandhiniDevi It's temp table which derived from query

Comment: when i added sum(count1) as total in query only i got errors